Cytoscape cannot handle HTTP response code [304 Not Modified]
This is a Vue SPA that uses Cytoscape.js to display a graph. Users can assign an image to each node, by either choosing a local image file or specifying the URL of an existing image. Both methods work correctly and things get transferred to Laravel server and saved correctly. Resulting image URL (or the user-specified URL in the latter case) is then saved in the database against that node. I can then fetch these nodes along with their image URLs from the client. However:
Cytoscape doesn't seem to be able to display background-image if the specified URL returns 304 - Not Modified status. The same URL display the image correctly if opened directly in the browser.
I have been playing with it for a few hours and it is kind of strange. If I upload the file from the client, I see the above problem. The upload itself works correctly as I'm able to access the image through the resulting URL. But the same URL would not work when specified in Cytoscape node's background-image, like this:
"style": {
  "background-image": (ele: NodeDataDefinition) => ele.data('image_url').url??'default.png',
}

On the other hand, if I use a URL that points to other servers like Bing or Google, those images appear to display correctly and never return 304, even when accessed multiple times (the browser doesn't cache them).
So my questions are:

Can we ask Cytoscape to fetch image from browser cache if server returns 304?
If not, can we ask the server (Laravel 10) to never return 304 and just serve the image as if there were a fresh request.

